# is there any way to mount function in sidedrawer?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I am trying to call the function using mounted in drawercontent.vue but its not working.

I tried the normal method like creating the function and called it with mounted when page load.

I have uploaded my full code because for the easiness to understand.

```
import Home from "./Home";
    import Browse from "./Browse";
    import Featured from "./Featured";
    import Search from "./Search";
    import Login from "./Login";
    import Settings from "./Settings";
    import * as utils from "~/shared/utils";
    import SelectedPageService from "~/shared/selected-page-service";   
    import * as appSettings from "tns-core-modules/application-settings"; 

    let methods = {
        onNavigationItemTap: (component) => {
            this.$navigateTo(component, {
                clearHistory: true
            });
            utils.closeDrawer();
        },
        feedData: () => {
            obj.userName = appSettings.getString("user_display_name")
            obj.userEmail = appSettings.getString("user_email")
            alert("data feeded")
        },
        logoutUser: () => {
            appSettings.clear();
            appSettings.remove("user_display_name");
            appSettings.remove("user_email");
            if(appSettings.getString("user_email") == null || appSettings.getString("user_email") == ''){
                alert("user email id removed");
            }
            if(appSettings.getString("user_display_name") == null || appSettings.getString("user_display_name") == ''){
                alert("user name removed");
            }
            utils.closeDrawer();
            this.$navigateTo(Login, {
                clearHistory: true
            });                
        }
    }

    let obj = {
        mounted: () => {
            SelectedPageService.getInstance().selectedPage$
                .subscribe((selectedPage) => this.selectedPage = selectedPage);
            methods.feedData();
            alert("data Feeded");
        },
        data: () => {
            return {
                Home: Home,
                Browse: Browse,
                Featured: Featured,
                Search: Search,
                Login: Login,
                Settings: Settings,
                selectedPage: "",
                userName:"",
                userEmail:""
            };
        },
        components: {
            Home,
            Browse,
            Featured,
            Search,
            Login,
            Settings
        },
        methods
    }

    export default {
        methods,
        obj
    }
</script>
```

the feeddata is not calling and i have set alert to check but no success.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: no i can't the code have gone in big complex state and i don't know how to add node modules in playground

Comment: I asked for a sample project, just the enough code to reproduce the issue not your entire project. Probably you won't have to add any npm modules to do so.

Comment: Its hard to implement in play ground having lots of error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have to move the declaration of methods at the top, and than you can call feedData inside you method:

```
let methods = {
    onNavigationItemTap: (component) => {
        this.$navigateTo(component, {
            clearHistory: true
        });
        utils.closeDrawer();
    },
    feedData: () => {
        this.userName = appSettings.getString("user_display_name");
        this.userEmail = appSettings.getString("user_email");
    }
};

let obj = {
    mounted: () => {
        SelectedPageService.getInstance().selectedPage$
            .subscribe((selectedPage) => this.selectedPage = selectedPage);
        methods.feedData();
        alert("datta Feeded");
    },
    data: () => {
        return {
            userName: "",
            userEmail: ""
        };
    },
    methods

};

export default {
    methods,
    obj
}
```

Comment: How do you call the feedData() ? Can you paste the code in you question?

Comment: I m calling it from mounted

Comment: I edit my answer. Check If it's a possible solution for you.

Comment: Show me how do you call the mounted method. Please give me more informations.

Comment: Navigating the pages doesnt work and the data feed all not working(editing my question adding full pagee of code) and i think mounted method auto call so i havent called it

Comment: When you export the methods how did you call the mounted() ? I think the problem is not in this file, but when you call the method.

Comment: can you tell me how can i call mounted coz in vue i think mounted is auto call on page load i dont know in vuenative app

Comment: Try to export only the obj, because I see you put the methods object inside obj. I advice you to use the chrome debugger or console.log instead of alert('..').

Comment: can you personaly help me. plz